# Create new React Component (chartpage) on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I'm really new to react.js and still practising

I wanted to render a ReChart component as a new page when the user selects a row in a table (Just to visualise the Data).

I tried something like this:

(had to insert here a semicolon cause the tag was not shown)

```
handleRowSelection(selectedRows) {
console.log('selectedRows: ' + selectedRows );
var myChart = React.createClass({
  render(){
      return(
         <MyChart value={selectedRows}>
       )
   }
})} 

export default class MyChart extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
  }
  render(){
  //must be generic
  return(
  <LineChart
  data={this.props.value}
  margin={{ top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 20, left: 20 }}>
  <CartesianGrid vertical={false} />
  <XAxis dataKey="id" label="myDataChart" />
  <YAxis domain={['auto', 'auto']} label="attribute" />
  <Tooltip />
  <Line dataKey="attribute" stroke="#3f51b5" dot={false} />
  </LineChart>
  )
};
```

Unfortunately it didnt help. Any Guesses here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is many of unnecessary "; " and " ` "  in your code like,  `<;MyChart value={selectedRows}>` and  `constructor(props){`` `. Please remove that.

Comment: man this is so messy, can you put it on jsfiddle, many unnecessary ``` which breaks everything!

Comment: thanks, messed up there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't write additional functions that have a render(). That is the purpose of the React class. Secondly, your original React component has no reference to handleClick(). It needs to look more like this:

```
class Thing extends Component {
  state = {
    fill: '#eee',
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({ fill: 'black' });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <svg fill={this.state.fill} onClick={this.handleClick} />
    );
  }
}
```

Clicking on the SVG will change the state, which will then cause the rerender.

Comment: its still weird too me, but thank you, I will try that out!